# Save integer as float

Tags: javascript

```
function prec(numb){
    var numb_string = numb.toString().split('.')

    return numb_string[(numb_string.length - 1)].length
}
function randy(minimum, maximum) {
    var most_accurate = Math.max ( prec(minimum), prec(maximum) );

    return ( ( Math.random() * ( maximum - minimum ) + minimum ).toFixed( most_accurate ) );
}

// returns random numbers between these points. 1 decimal place of precision:
console.log( randy(2.4,4.4) );

// returns random numbers between these points. 3 decimal places of precision:
console.log( randy(2.443,4.445) );

// returns random numbers between these points. Want 3 decimal places of precision. However, get 0:
console.log( randy(2.000,4.000) );

// Why do I get 0 decimal places? Because floats are rounded into integers automatically:

console.log( 4.0 ); // want 4.0 to be logged. Instead I get '4'
```

You don't need to read how the functions work. Just the console logs.

Basically, I need to return a random number between two points to a degree of precision. The precision is automatically derived from the most precise float passed to the `randy` function.

This works fine when the number range is `3.5` `3.7` or `34.4322` `800.3233` but not `2.0`, `3.0` or `4.0000`, `5.0000`

Then the number is appears to be automatically saved as an integer:

`console.log( 2.0 ) //=> 2`

**I want to extend the Number prototype so that `2.0` is saved as `2.0` so that this function can find the precision:**

```
function prec(numb){
    var numb_string = numb.toString().split('.')

    return numb_string[(numb_string.length - 1)].length
}
```

It currently thinks that `3.000000000` has a precision of 0 decimal places because if `3E8` is passed in as the `numb` parameter, it's read as `3`. I want it read as `3.000000000`

While I can do this `randy(2.toFixed(3),3.toFixed(3))` it gets unreadable and it would be undeniably nicer to do this for smaller precisions: `randy(2.000,3.000)`.

Is this possible?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxCeK/2/)

Comment: I don't understand, why do you say 4.0 is "saved as" 4?  Do you mean "displays as" 4?  The number of decimal places shown is really a string issue (display), not a storage issue.  JavaScript "stores" all numbers as IEEE754 64-bit floating values.  Can you clarify why "toFixed" is not acceptable for you?  Do you just want to actually change the value so as to not have to write `toFixed`?

Comment: Re "I've created a function that returns the precision of a float", No, you've created a function that counts the number of decimal places in a number after it's been rounded for stringification.

Comment: `number.toFixed(1)` will preserve the `.0`.

Comment: There is no `int` or `float` in JavaScript. More surprisingly, there is no `Number` class at all. Every number is store as a `Double`, and there are only a `Number` wrapper and a `Number` primitive.

Comment: If you don't want to use .toFixed() then store the original values as strings.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - If you look closely at the documentation, you would find that there is no mention of `class` anywhere. As I said in my comment, there are only a Number [object] wrapper and a Number primitive.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - You're splitting hairs; classes don't mean the same thing as they do in language like Java and C#. What would be an example of a valid "class" in Javascript?

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for that useless comment.

Comment: @RayToal I want to actually change the value so as to not have to write `toFixed`

Comment: @Starkers, saying that you're trying to get something that doesn't exist is not useless.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - There is no class in JavaScript as far as I know since JS is a prototype-based language. You can emulate a class by defining custom object types, but it's still not a class though.

Comment: @Stankers See below. This is guaranteed to cause you problems at some point or the other.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 no classes, but you can still overload methods on object prototypes (if that's really what you want).

Comment: If you're trying to get any number to always act as a float when read, to keep from having to type `.toFixed(n)`, is not a great idea.

Answer (score 4):

There is a clever way to solve this problem , is to define a class that helps you managing the number values and the decimal values.

```
function HappyNumber()
{
    this.value = (typeof(arguments[0]) == "number") ? arguments[0] : 0;
    this.decimal = (typeof(arguments[1]) == "number") ? arguments[1] : 0;
    this.Val = function()
    {
        return parseFloat(this.value.toFixed(this.decimal));
    }
    this.toString = function()
    {
        return (this.value.toFixed(this.decimal)).toString();
    }
}
```

## How this class works

Now first thing to do is to create a new number like this

```
var Num = HappyNumber(4.123545,3); 
// first argument is the value 
// and second one is decimal
```

To get the value of your variable, you should use the function `Val` like this

```
console.log(Num.Val()); // this one prints 4.123 on your console
```

The most important part is this one, when you use the `toString` function it return your number

```
Num.toString() // it returns "4.123"
(new HappyNumber(4,4)).toString(); // it returns "4.0000"
```

Now you pass arguments as (HappyNumber), and inside your function use toString and it returns the right value you need and it works with numbers like **`1.00 2.000 4.00000`**

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want. (Warning: This is probably not a good idea.)

```
Number.prototype.toString = function () { return this.toFixed(1); }
```

Comment: Actually, he specifically said he doesn't want to use `toFixed` because of the performance hit.

Comment: Actually, he didn't say that. He said that he would consider _not_ using a convenience function _if_ it caused a performance hit.

Comment: @ikegami "Like I say, I want to extend the Number class to keep the rest of the code clean and not have to write .toFixed() about a dozen times." so this is exactly what OP is looking for...

Comment: I suppose an alternative could be: http://jsfiddle.net/gdLP5/1 No comment on any "performance hit".